# Facing issue in this api , unable to send the post request

Tags: node.js, express, postman

```
router.post('/testing',async function (req, res) {
  // res.send(config.get("name") +": media service is up :)");
  // res.json({ "success": `Testing successfull` });
  try{
    // logger("info",`Req Body ${req}`)
    const orgId = req.query.orgId; 
    // console.log(`The orgID is ${orgId}`)
    // res.json({ "success": `Testing successfull ${orgId}` });
    // return res.status(200)  
    // return res.status(200)   //
    const locationID = req.query.locationID;  
    //   console.log(`The orgID is ${locationID}`)
    // res.json({ "success": `Testing successfull ${locationID}` });
    // return res.status(200)      
    let intent = req.body.intent;
    let type = req.body.type;    
    if(orgId == null || locationID == null || intent == null || type ==null){
      return res.status(400).json({"Details" : "Please provide complete info"});
    }
    let text = "";
    let fallback = "";
    let containsRichText = false;
    const active = 0;
    const template_data = "suggestions";
    // const messageID = uuidv4();
    //cases
    if(type === 'text' || type === 'richText'){
      text = handleEmojis(req.body.text);
    //       res.json({ "success": `Testing successfull ${text}` });
    // return res.status(200)
      fallback = text;
    //      res.json({ "success": `Testing successfull ${fallback}` });
    // return res.status(200)
         if (type === 'richText') {
        containsRichText = true;
      }
   
    } else if (type === 'suggestions'){
      text = handleEmojis(req.body.text);
       fallback = text;
       let suggestions = req.body.suggestions;
       //corner cases
       if(!Array.isArray(suggestions) || suggestions.length==0 || suggestions.length > 13){
        return res.status(400).json({"Details" : "Invalid suggestions format"});
       }
       const formattedSuggestions = suggestions.map((suggestion , ind)=>{
        let cardName = suggestion.text;
        let postbackData = suggestion.postback;
        let action = suggestion.action;
        if(cardName.length > 25){
          throw new Error('Card name should be less than or equal to  25 characters');
        }
        if(!cardName || !postbackData || cardName.trim().length===0 || postbackData.trim().length === 0){
          throw new Error(`Invalid card name or postback data at index ${ind}`);
        }
        if (action) {
          if (action.startsWith('http')) {
            // Handle URL action
            if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(action)) {
              throw new Error(`Invalid URL format at index ${ind}`);
            }
          } else if (action.startsWith('+')) {
            // Handle phone number action
            if (!/^\+\d{1,15}$/.test(action)) {
              throw new Error(`Invalid phone number format at index ${ind}`);
            }
          } else {
            throw new Error(`Invalid action format at index ${ind}`);
          }
        }
        const formattedSuggestion = action
          ? {
          action: {
          text: cardName,
          postbackData: postbackData,
          [action.startsWith('http') ? 'openUrlAction' : 'dialAction']: {
            [action.startsWith('http') ? 'url' : 'phoneNumber']: action
          }
        }
        }
        :{
        reply: {
          text: cardName,
          postbackData: postbackData
        }
        };
     
  return formattedSuggestion;
       })
       //formatted object later going to add this in database
      //  console.log("Before formattedSuggestionObject block");
       const formattedSuggestionObject = {
        text: text,
        fallback: fallback,
        // suggestions: formattedSuggestions
       };
       if (containsRichText) {
        formattedSuggestionObject.containsRichText = true;
      }
      if(formattedSuggestions){
      formattedSuggestionObject.suggestions  = formattedSuggestions   
      }
      // console.log("Formatted Suggestion Object:", formattedSuggestionObject); // Add this line for debugging

      // return res.status(200).json(formattedSuggestionObject);
      const temp = JSON.stringify(formattedSuggestionObject);
       const insertResult = await dao.insertIntentResponse(locationID,intent,temp,template_data,active,type);
      logger("info", "Inserted intent response: " + JSON.stringify(insertResult));
      res.status(200).json({ "status": "success" });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ "Details": "Invalid type" });
    }
  } catch(error){
    logger("error" , "error in /add_intent_response " + error);
    res.status(500).json({ "error": "An internal server error occurred" });
  }
});
```

So i am using the function addIntentResponse to pass the parameters, and then insert the data into my local database. But the API is not working properly, it is sending requests but i can't see any response on my Postman. I can also share the function if someone needs to debug this problem.

NoneBashCSSCC#ElixirErlangGoGraphQLGroovyHaskellHTMLINIJavaJavaScriptJSONKotlinLispLuaMermaid DiagramNixObjective-COCamlPerlPHPPowershellPythonRubyRustScalaSQLSoliditySwiftTOMLTypeScriptVisual BasicYAMLZigCopy

User input and Expected Output  :

```
Plaintext: 
{
  "intent":"faq",
  "type": "text", 
  "text":"this will be the user text"
}

# 2. For rich text -- tet with bold, italics, hyperlink

richText : 
{
  "intent":"faq",
  "type": "richText",
  "text": "Hello, here is some **bold text**, *italicized text*, and a [link](https://www.google.com)."

}

#3. For suggestions 
# With reply type only
suggestionsReply :
{
  "intent":"faq",
  "type":"suggestions",
  "text": "some random text",
  "suggestions": [
    {"text" : "Book Appointment", "postback": "b_apt", "action": "www.google.com"},
    {"text": "Abc", "postback": "abc"},
    {"text": "bcd", "postback": "bcd"},
    {"text": "call clinic", "postback": "call", "action": "+4562233"}
   ]
}



# Plain -text output
{
  "text": "Thanks!!\nI have sent your query to our expert team.\nThey will reach out to you soon to answer your query.",
  "fallback": "Thanks!!\nI have sent your query to our expert team.\nThey will reach out to you soon to answer your query."
}



#richText output 
{
  "text": "Thanks!!\nI have sent your query to our expert team.\nThey will reach out to you soon to answer your query.",
  "fallback": "Thanks!!\nI have sent your query to our expert team.\nThey will reach out to you soon to answer your query.",
  "containsRichText": true
}



#suggestions-expected output :
{
  "text": "Sorry! {Name} can not write anything please select from the chips below ",
  "fallback": "Sorry! you can not write anything please select from the chips below only",
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "reply": {
        "text": "Book a Appointment",
        "postbackData": "b_apt"
      }
    },
    {
      "action": {
        "text": "Visit Website",
        "postbackData": "ignore",
        "openUrlAction": {
          "url": "https://xyz.io/"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "action": {
        "text": "Call Clinic",
        "postbackData": "ignore",
        "dialAction": {
          "phoneNumber": "+12223334444"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "reply": {
        "text": "Main menu",
        "postbackData": "menu"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```